# Why if can expand instead of ifee in vim-snippets and ultisnips?

Tags: vim, plugins, ultisnips, vim-snipmate

I have installed `vim-snippets`  and `ultisnips` with plugin manager--`pathogen` this way.

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle
sudo git clone https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets.git
cd ~/.vim/bundle && git clone git://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips.git
```

Set configuration in `.vimrc`.

```
execute pathogen#infect()
execute pathogen#helptags()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<tab>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger="<tab>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger="<s-tab>"
let g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories=['/home/debian9/.vim/UltiSnips']
```

I list `if ife ifee` structure in my python.snippets.

```
cat .vim/bundle/vim-snippets/UltiSnips/python.snippets
snippet if "If" b
if ${1:condition}:
    ${2:${VISUAL:pass}}
endsnippet

snippet ife "If / Else" b
if ${1:condition}:
    ${2:${VISUAL:pass}}
else:
    ${3:pass}
endsnippet

snippet ifee "If / Elif / Else" b
if ${1:condition}:
    ${2:${VISUAL:pass}}
elif ${3:condition}:
    ${4:pass}
else:
    ${5:pass}
endsnippet
```

Now it is time to edit a `test.py` file with vim.

Input `#!` and press `tab` can expand into :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Input `if` and press `tab` can expand into :

```
if condition:
```

Why Input `ifee` and press `tab` can expand into nothing in my vim?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file `.vim/bundle/vim-snippets/UltiSnips/python.snippets` that you show is not included in the ultisnips directory you configured in your vimrc (`/home/debian9/.vim/UltiSnips`).

You could try:

- to change your configuration:

  ```
  let g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories=['/home/debian9/.vim/bundle/vim-snippets/UltiSnips']
  ```
- or alternatively, to check the file `/home/debian9/.vim/UltiSnips/python.snippets` in order to see if the right snippets are defined.